# Adding new resources dynamically - CoAP

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, coap, californium

Once CoAP server is started I need to add new resources dynamically. But I have to stop and start the server again in order to access new resources. I suppose adding new resources same as adding a new HTTP servlet into already started HTTP server.

Here I added source code which is used for adding dynamic resources. If I am missing anything here let me know.

```
private static CoapServer server;

public CoAPEventAdapter(InputEventAdapterConfiguration eventAdapterConfiguration,
                        Map<String, String> globalProperties) {
    this.eventAdapterConfiguration = eventAdapterConfiguration;
    this.globalProperties = globalProperties;
    if(server == null){
        server = new CoapServer();
        server.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void connect() {
    registerDynamicEndpoint(eventAdapterConfiguration.getName());
    isConnected = true;
} 

private void registerDynamicEndpoint(String adapterName) {
        server.stop();
        server.add(new HelloWorldResource(adapterName));
        server.start();
}


class HelloWorldResource extends CoapResource {

    public HelloWorldResource(String resourceName) {
        // set resource identifier
        super(resourceName);
        // set display name
        getAttributes().setTitle("Hello-World Resource");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {

        // respond to the request
        exchange.respond("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to add a CoapResource dynamically:

```java
@Override
public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {
    server.getRoot().add(new CoapResource("dynstatus") {
        @Override
        public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {
            System.err.println("dynstatus!!!");
        }
    });
```

And was able to call it.